# If statement for ObjectMapper?

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

I'm trying to not set a value ONLY if it's present in the JSON. I want to do something like this:

```
    if (map["doc.type"] != nil) {
      picturePath <- map["doc.type"]
    }
```

I'm using this ObjectMapper framework:
https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

Comment: are you asking on how to do this with RestKit?

Comment: You might want to explain what ObjectMapper is. The tag doesn't have any info.

Comment: I updated the question to show what the ObjectMapper is.

Answer (score 0):

<- is mapping operator which returns optional type. If key "doc.type" is not presented picturePath is nil.

If you would like to full fill picturePath based on different keys, the best way is probably to use helpers variables and then assign picturePath based on them.

e.g.:

```
var optionalPicturePath: String? = map["doc.type"]
if optionalPicturePath != nil {
  picturePath = optionalPicturePath
}
```